# Yocto project, try to add my device driver config into the Linux kernel configuration file

Tags: linux-device-driver, yocto

I am trying to add my own device driver to Linux kernel with Yocto Project.
I added my configuration like `CONFIG_MY_DRIVER=y` into the `defconfig` file in the BSP layer folder, `meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-my/` and modified the bb file by adding `SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"`.

After BitBake, I found that the `.config` file in the build directory didn't have `CONFIG_MY_DRIVER=y`, but the `.config.old` file did. It seems that the `.config` file has been overwritten by some background task. I am not familiar with it, can anyone help me to figure out it?

Comment: If you use Yocto kernel, it should be added with fragment system explained on [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-config-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

At the same you have to copy the `CONFIG_MY_DRIVER=y` into `receipe-kernel/linux/linux-my/defconfig` ,`defconfig` should reflected after adding the option into the `yocto` layer, Then fetch into kernel `.bblayer`

```
SRC_URI = "git address file://defconfig"
```

then start the `bitbake` server.